# Switching between chart types on fly

Tags: google-visualization

Is it possible to switch between chart types (pie and column) by clicking on the according button?

For example I want to have two buttons and once I click on the first button it will display pie chart.

Comment: This looks very straightforward. Have you tried it.

Comment: Yes, I tried it: by replacing pie chart with bar chart but I have to reload browser to see the correct result = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward

```
function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', 3],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
      ['Zucchini', 1],
      ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var piechart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

onyour click handler simply replace

```
var barchart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
```